# passing optional dataframe parameter in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Rather than explicitly specifying the `DataFrame` columns in the code below, I'm trying to give an option of passing the name of the data frame in itself, without much success.

The code below gives a

> "ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions" error.

I've tried another couple of ideas but they all lead to errors of one form or another.

Apart from this issue, when the parameters are passed as explicit `DataFrame` columns, `p` as a single column, and `q` as a list of columns, the code works as desired.  Is there a clever (or indeed any) way of passing in the data frame so the columns can be assigned to it implicitly?

```
def cdf(p, q=[], datafr=None):
    if datafr!=None:
        p = datafr[p]
        for i in range(len(q)):
            q[i]=datafr[q[i]]
...
(calculate conditional probability tables for p|q)
```

to summarize:

current usage:

```
cdf(df['var1'], [df['var2'], df['var3']])
```

desired usage:

```
cdf('var1', ['var2', 'var3'], datafr=df)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `if datafr != None:` to `if datafr is not None:`

Pandas doesn't know which value in the dataframe you are trying to compare to None so it throws an error. `is` checks if both `datafr` and `None` are the pointing to the same object, which is a more stringent identity check. See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/1435522).

Additional tips:

- Python iterates over lists

  ```
  #change this 
  for i in range(len(q)):
        q[i]=datafr[q[i]]
  #to this:
  for i in q:
     q[i] = datafr[q]
  ```
- If q is a required parameter don't do q = [ ] when defining your function. If it is an optional parameter, ignore me.
- Python can use position to match the arguments passed to the function call to with the parameters in the definition.

  ```
  cdf('var1', ['var2', 'var3'], datafr=df)
  #can be written as:
  cdf('var1', ['var2', 'var3'], df)
  ```

Comment: Thanks.  The datafr is not None did the trick.   I had already tried the list iteration for the q[i]'s, and it threw an error, OTOH the code I had seems to work.